# How to reference an SQS queue which has not been created yet in CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I have a defined queue resource in my cloud formation template. Now. in the same template, I am defining a queue policy in which I want to allow certain action on the queue. For the attribute "Resource" in the policy statement, how can I reference the Queue Name / arn since it hasn't been created yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get ARN from queue's [return values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html#aws-properties-sqs-queues-return-values). Depending on exactly how you are defining your policy it could be:

```
!GetAtt <your-queue-resource>.Arn
```

Comment: How to get the value of your-queue-resource .Do I just go with the logical name ?

Comment: @AnitAggarwal Yes, its logical name.